# Insert row on top of pandas dataframe with index 1 day before

Tags: insert, pandas, indexing, row, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the index consisting of dates with daily frequency.
How is possible to add a row on top of the dataframe with index which is one-day before the first element of the original dataframe?

Thanks regards

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the dataframe after you add the new element by using,

```
df.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
position_to_insert = 0
df.index.insert(position_to_insert , df.index[0] + timedelta(days = -1))
```

hope this help